# New record isn't saved and no error messages

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I am trying to save a new row into a quote, but Yii doens't save the QuoteRow. It only saves the new service (Yes the DB-structure is a bit weird). I can't seem to figure it out. If the row doesn't get saved, $qr->save() should return false but it doesn't. The service is successfuly inserted, however the quoterow isn't.

```
$service = new Services;
$service->label = $row['title'] ?: "Övrigt";
$service->is_priced_per_unit = 1;
$service->price_per_unit = $row['price']*0.8;
$service->is_default = 0;
$service->rot_deductable = (int)isset($row['rot']);
$service->rot_deduction_percentage = 0.5;
if (!$service->save()) $this->addError('Kunde inte spara raden',$service->getErrors());
    else{
    $qr = new QuoteRows;
    $qr->quote_service_id = Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();
    $qr->quote_id = $id;
    $qr->unit_size = $row['amount'] ?: 0;
    $qr->raw_price = $row['price']*0.8*($row['amount'] ?: 1);
    $qr->is_rot_deductable = isset($row['rot']) ? 1 : 0;
    $qr->is_active = 1;

    if (!$qr->save()) $this->addError('Kunde inte spara raden',$qr->getErrors());
}
```

If $qr isn't saved, i should get the errors. I've also tried to validate $qr by using the validate-function, and it claims that it is perfectly valid!

Comment: Just because it passes Yii's validation doesn't mean there isn't a mysql error on the insert. Have you check your error logs? Do you have debug mode enabled?

Comment: Pitchinnate - does that mean save() would hide a SQL error?

Answer (score 1):

Either use debug mode, or use a beforeValidate, beforeSave method with print_r($model)within the model;

If all the attributes are set, the new data should be saved; obvious something is missing.

Comment: I just tried to comment out the ActiveRecord-part and run a SQL-query instead with the very same result. However, if i just before the part where i execute the SQL-query does ´die($sql)´ instead, and then uses the printed SQL-query and run it against my DB manually it works just fine...

I have never ran into an issue like this before, it feels almost like the db-connection gets into some kind of stage where it stops working at all, and the logs shows me nothing

Comment: maybe your app is not connected to the db; it happened to me once, i don't know how, but i had to force the connection; also, `Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();` might not work properly; many things could happen on the db

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I had forgotten the beforSave method. It returned false but I had not set any errors. So the return array of getErrors method was empty.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your beforeSave, afterSave functions return true

Answer (score 0):

You are using two models in the same controller. It is better to import all the fields in 'QuoteRows' to 'Services' publicly in 'Services model'. And while saving get the values using the POST method and save it through QuoteRows model.You can add conditions for validation in 'Service Model' too.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using an event in your model that doesn't return true. eg.`public function beforeSave() {....... return true;//must return true after everything}`