# updating database details in yii2

Tags: yii2

**YII not updating**

Tried to GOOGLE but no difference.

```
 public function actionEdit($id)
    {
        $model = AddMix::findOne($id);

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()){

        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('detailssubmited');

        return $this->redirect(['mixes','id'=>$model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('editmix',['model'=>$model]);
}
```

It does not update instead it returns same view with changed value but not in database

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING at us?

Comment: Please use lower case when typing

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen because it isnt working? :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759514/model-save-not-working-in-yii2

Answer (score 2):

It fail the validation so do not enter into the `if` and re-render the form.

New data are shown because of `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())`

check:

```
$model->getErrors();
```

see [getErrors](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#getErrors()-detail) documentation