# Can't insert into database with save()

Tags: sql, database, yii

I am having an issue inserting a record into the database. I am a beginner with the Yii framework, so I may have made some stupid mistakes.

This is from the SiteController

```
public function actionCreatePost(){
     $model = new PostForm();

     $post = new Post();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $post->body = $model->body;
        $post->title = $model->title;
        $post->save();

        return $this->redirect('index');
    }else {
        return $this->render('createPost', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

This is from the Post class

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'createdAtAttribute' => 'created_at',
            'updatedAtAttribute' => 'updated_at',
            'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
        ],
        [
            'class' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
            'createdByAttribute' => 'id_author',
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: take a look at this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759514/model-save-not-working-in-yii2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have created a PostForm class for the form (which is correct) but you are then trying to load the response into the Post class - a completely different class. This won’t work without modification.

If you have a look at the response:

```
var_dump(Yii:$app->request->post());
```

You will see the form data is located within the PostForm key. Yii will therefore only load the data into the PostForm class.

The correct solution is therefore to create a savePost() function within the PostForm eg:

```
public function savePost(){
$model = new Post();
$model->propertyABC = $this->propertyABC
...etc...
$model->save();
```

So the action would appear as follows:

```
$model = new PostForm();
If($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
$model->savePost();
```

The other option is to rename the key from PostForm to Post. Yii will then load the data but this is not the best approach as it is a bit obscure.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the issue is with the validation.

I can see several issues I will point out. First, I cannot figure out why are you creating a `new PostForm`, loading the data in it and verifying it, just to dump some values in a `new Post` and save it. Are there some functions, you are running in the `PostForm` model, that are triggered by `load` or `verify`? If that is not the case, I would suggest dropping one of the models, and using only the other. Usually, that is the `Form` model. It serves as a link between the `ActiveForm` and the `model` handling everything. You can do everything in the `createPost()` function in the `Form` model, and then in the controller it will look like

```
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
          $model->save();
          return $this->redirect('index');
    }
```

Second of all, you can dump `post->getErrors()` before the save to see if there are any errors with the validation. What you can also do, is call `$post->save(false)` instead. If you pass false to it, it will not trigger `$post->validate()`, and some errors can be neglected. Please, let me know if there is anything unclear.